# Linux Distro with PPTP/L2TP client support and IP Forwarding

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, l2tp, webgui

I'm looking for a  lightweight linux distro with a nice web based front end that I can throw on a VM to act as a secondary gateway out of my network through a VPN. I currently have a debian VM with ip forwarding setup which is doing the job but something with a nice web front end would suit me better (allowing me to change VPN servers quickly for example).

Any ideas?